# Firefox Developer shows wrong this-object in callbacks of Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox-developer-tools

I have to deal with an Angular app that I haven't made and switched to Firefox Developer for its rich feature set, recently. Here I noticed something weird.

In every event callback of every component `this` will reference the component instance, obviously. The Chromium dev tools seem to know it and resolve this in the callbacks, properly:

[image: Chromium Dev Tools: this outside of event callback]

[image: Chromium Dev Tools: this inside of event callback]

However, if I debug the same with Firefox Developer Edition their dev tools show the wrong `this` referencing (I think it's the caller instead of the component):

[image: Firefox Developer Edition Dev Tools: this outside of event callback]

[image: Firefox Developer Edition Dev Tools: this inside of event callback]

This is utterly wrong, because the app works in Firefox and there are no errors, despite the dev tools saying `this.user_helper` is undefined.

Maybe I miss something here, or did I spot a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a Firefox DevTools bug.

What you are describing very much sounds like [bug 1710492](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1710492) (Showing wrong variable value while debugging when hovering variable or using watch). [Bug 1680228](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1680228) (Some variables show undefined when they are not) may also be related to this.